# Accessing a specific $index object inside a JSON Array

Tags: angularjs, json

I have this object:

```
 var obj = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Ben",
        role: [{
            roleId: 1,
            roleName: role01
        },
        {
            roleId: 2,
            roleName: role02
        }]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "Anna",
        role: [{
            roleId: 3,
            roleName: role03
        },
        {
            roleId: 4,
            roleName: role04
        }]
    }];
```

I want to access Anna's 'roleId: 3' inside an ng-repeat. How can I achieve that? Here's what I tried so far:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in obj">
 <td>{{item.obj[$index].role[0].roleId}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i think you just need to use <td>{{ item.role[0].roleId }}</td>

Comment: @JP thought about switching to Angular 2/4 ?

Comment: @vibs2006 maybe not for now because I already started the project. Thanks for the recommendation anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specifically access 'Anna's role id , you should do without ng-repeat

```
<tr>
 <td>{{obj[1].role[0].roleId }}</td>
</tr>
```

if you want all person's id you should do

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in obj">
 <td>{{ item.role[0].roleId }}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in obj">
 <td>{{ item.role[0].roleId }}</td>
</tr>
```